# SSO - SAML, Redirect a user to a specified landing page after successful log in

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, opensaml

I am implementing SSO where I am the Identity Provider, right now I am able to successfully log into the Service Provider. But it takes me to the home page. I want to specify the landing page URL when I post the response.
Have searched quite a lot but could not find anything convincing.
Do not quite know which element of the SAML response carries the Landing page URL or is the in the form that I have to specify. Using java and opensaml libraries to generate the response.

Comment: how did you do this  , I am stuck on task in which you succeed , How did you create saml

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Though it is not in the SAML specs, a de-facto standard is to use the `RelayState` element for that. It is added as a parameter in the response in addition to the `SAMLResponse` parameter and value of the `landing` URL. Sample HTML page from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0 for an IDP using the `POST` binding for the response:

```
<form method="post" action="https://sp.example.com/SAML2/SSO/POST" ...>
    <input type="hidden" name="SAMLResponse" value="<response>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="<url>" />
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Edit:
Just to be clear, the `RelayState` parameter declaration *is* part of the specs and it is included to allow for passing *arbitrary* state between SP and IDP. Using it for passing a URL that defines the landing page is not defined in the spec but is de-facto standard usage. Any usage of `RelayState` in IDP-init-SSO would depend on a pair-wise agreement between IDP and SP and this is just an agreement that makes sense, is useful and thus has been widely adopted.

Comment: Is it safe if I pass a non-encoded URL. The SP end gives me a "not found", guess they do not decode it at their end. But it works without encoding.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say on the wire it is URL-encoded when passing it in the HTTP POST; by placing it verbatim in the HTML form, the browser will URL-encode it. So in the sample that I gave you would place the actual value in `<url>`. I will edit the text.

Comment: Not to nit-pick, but `RelayState` is absolutely in the [bindings specs](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf) for SAML 2.0 (i.e. it is stronger than a de-facto standard).  The **HTTP POST**, **HTTP Redirect**, and **HTTP Artifact** bindings all include rules for `RelayState`, though none _require_ its use.

Comment: `RelayState`'s name is standardized but it's value is not.

Comment: updated the answer with info about that last comment